# Crystal reports on server side

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Can it possible to create crystal reports at server side like rdl(SSRS) reports. Or is there any cystal report server that host that reports.If yes how can we access those from applcation.Please help me out.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a number of options including:

- Crystal Reports Server: http://www.crystalreportsserver.co.uk/overview.aspx
- Custom .net "Web" Application: http://www.dotnetking.com/ArticleDetails.aspx?ArticleID=44
- Existing 3rd Party Application (more for scheduling rather than on-demand): http://www.kenhamady.com/bookmarks.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create the report on the server, serialize if and pass it across to your application then deserialize it to view it. This is exactly what my reports service does.